# Could not start MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server

I was doing my school project, i have all default installation on Visual Studio 2022, using ASP.NET (not core), when i was trying to create a database or connect to existing database and this error message shows up

[Error connecting to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPWaz.png)

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,Error 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

What should I do?

After trace the error log at my `MSSQLLocalDB` folder, the last line of the log shows

> There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO, The current file is on \MSSQLLocalDB\master.mdf

I also traced my event viewer,

> Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
> The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
> Reported at line: 3714

I also tried using `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB` and all it shows is

> Start of LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" failed because of the following error:
> Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start

I even tried uninstall all folder regarding to the visual studio and Microsoft SQL Server. But after re-install, it still cannot run.

Comment: What is your logical and physical sector size? `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:` where `c:` is the drive containing `master.mdf`. You need the `Bytes Per Sector` and `Bytes Per Physical Sector`. If they are different then your drive is not formatted correctly. But I don't think this prevents starting SQL Server, there is probably something else in the logs. Are you sure the connection string is correct, what is it?

Comment: My `Bytes Per Sector` is `512` and `Bytes Per Physical Sector` is `4096`, for the connection string for my existing database is `public const string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StudentDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";`, i got this database from other teammates as they can create database. Because I already have problem create database.

Comment: OK you definitely have an issue with the logical sector size, it should have been formatted at 4096 to match the physical size. But I don't think that would cause a failure to start. Are there any other notable log errors? Side note: `AttachDbFilename` is a really bad idea, it does weird stuff with copying the database then deleting it on close. Just attach your database normally using SSMS and `CREATE DATABASE...`

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
In the error.log, i only can find  `There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\master.mdf.`
Others are just informational message, no action required.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems the root cause is because of the bytes per sector needs to be same with bytes per physical sector then re-install the whole thing again.
Thanks again, your a savior to me as I stuck at this problem for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

May be something is corrupted at the filesystem level, or the database level.
You can run tools such as `chkdsk c: /f` (assuming your localdb installation is on c: drive)

You can also try to create a new instance of LocalDB and see if the problem persists -

```
sqllocaldb create dec7instance
sqllocaldb start dec7instance
sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\dec7instance"
```

Comment: I tried to create new instance in LocalDB, still the instance could not start.